# Is deallocate() necessary before using new in VHDL?

Tags: memory-leaks, vhdl

When using `new` for an access type in VHDL, must I `deallocate()` before using `new`?

I understand you need to use `deallocate()` to prevent leaking when you are done with the access type, I'm just not sure whether using it before `new` is redundant or needed.

e.g.

```
testAccess : process
   type string_ptr is access string;
   variable tmpString : string_ptr;
   variable loopNum   : natural := 0;
begin
   tmpString := new string'("Test Loop: " & to_string(loopNum));
   report "String = " & tmpString.all;
   deallocate(tmpString); --is this neccessary?
   tmpString := new string'("New String Usage");
   report "String = " & tmpString.all;
   loopNum := loopNum + 1;
   deallocate(tmpString); --is this neccessary? (assuming we always loop back to first new)
   wait for 1 us;
end process;
```

Comment: No, it's necessary after you've finished with the data allocated with `new`. What's the difference? The example above (correctly) doesn't deallocate before the first `new`. (And in a small short simulation you can omit it and hope you get away with the memory leak, but it's not recommended in robust code)

Comment: @BrianDrummond I agree with everything except I confused by the text in parentheses - did you mean "And in a small short simulation you can omit all of the calls to deallocate, but it is not recommended in robust code."  The way it is written, it seems to refer to "deallocate before the first new" which should not be necessary since the pointer is initially null.

Comment: I meant, you can omit all deallocation if the simulation is short enough to tolerate memory leaks (assuming an OS can reclaim all leaked memory on simulation exit)

Comment: With VHDL-2017 (currently in the release process), we rewrote the LRM to get garbage collection, so deallocate will be unnecessary in the future.